# How to use a helper from another helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to cleanly refer to helper functions from other helpers. `include` is one way, but that creates a mess of the namespace.

- Is there a way to refer to a helper using its full namespace?
- Is there a way to organize helper code with folders and namespaces?

Comment: Since rails 4 all helpers are now loaded in the views (in older versions of rails it was not), so you can just refer/use another helper-method from another helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails helpers are just modules that are included in the view context. The view context is what Rails passes to ERB and which serves as the implicit *self* in your views.

You can simply refer to methods from your other helpers in a helper since they are all thrown into the same bag.

```
# app/helper/foo.rb
module FooHelper
  def foo_helper_method
    "oof morf olleH"
  end
end

# app/helpers/bar.rb
module BarHelper
  def bar_helper_method
    foo_helper_method.reverse
  end
end
```

This works since when you call `<%= bar_helper_method %>` in your view `foo_helper_method` is called on *self*. And *self* is the view context which has already included both `FooHelper` and `BarHelper`.

Since Rails 4 every file in `app/helpers` into is included in the view context.

Helpers are the smelly armpits of Rails. Its where all that junk code thats to complex for the view ends up. The methods all get included in the same object so its basically just a step up from defining a bunch of global methods (at least they are somewhat encapsulated). Its simple and it lets you get the job done and write really succinct views. If you need something more complex then helpers are not where its at.

A common solution to the problem is the decorator / view model / presenter pattern. But that comes with a fair share of complexity.

> Is there a way to refer to a helper using its full namespace?

No. The helper is just included in the view context. Its just a module mix-in. Not magic. If you want to declare a method in your helper thats only used from other helpers you could declare it as a module method:

```
module AdminHelper
  def self.some_method
  end
end

module AdminHelper
  def self.some_method
  end
end

# app/helpers/bar.rb
module BarHelper
  def bar_helper_method
    AdminHelper.some_method
  end
end
```

But in this case `self` is the module itself and not the view context so you will run into issues if you try to use other helper methods in a singleton module method without passing in the view context.

> Is there a way to organize helper code with folders and namespaces?

Yes. Rails will automatically look through the subfolders of `app/helpers` and include every module found.

But that won't really help you avoid naming clashes as they are all included in the same object. If two modules define the same method then the last one included wins.